# Rails gem outh2 authorize_url seems to get changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

I am trying to authenticate using oauth2 against a 3rd party API.

I am using the ruby gem oauth2 - https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2

The "authorize_url" method insists on adding an oauth subfolder to my URL.

So I want this: https://oauth.companyname.com/authorize?

But I get: https://oauth.companyname.com/oauth/authorize?

```
    client_id = "Demo"

    client_secret = "blablabla"

    site_path = 'https://oauth.companyname.com'

    client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, :site => site_path)

    client.auth_code.authorize_url
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `authorize_url` option when you are defining the client:

```rb
client = OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, authorize_url: 'authorize', site: site_path)
client.auth_code.authorize_url
# => https://oauth.companyname.com/authorize?client_id=Demo&response_type=code
```